# I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript

I didn't know how to program when I asked this question but I was looking for a way to obfuscate email addresses so bots would have a harder time scrapping them off the website. I was trying to have javascript fill in the email address on page load.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function emailTrainer(trainersName, userName, domainName){
                var tName = trainersName;
                var uName = userName;
                var dName = domainName;
                var subject = 'Questions&#32;about&#32;training'

                document.write('<a herf="mailto:' + uName + '@' + dName '&#63;Subject=' + subject + '">Email ' + tName + '</a>');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```html
    <address>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            emailTrainer('Name', 'email', 'Domain');
        </script>
    </address>
```

Comment: What's it supposed to do, and what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: you have a typo: `herf` should be `href`

Comment: What's your question? You need to explain the issue and what you've tried.

Comment: also you re using jQuery when you write `$(document)`. Are you including it, but especially, do you know what are you doing?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `<script>` tag inside the `<address>` tag?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site to solve complex problems with crazy out of the box solutions. This is not a beginners learning and Q&A site. Visit w3schools to learn about features youre learning before copy pasting and running for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You define `emailTrainer` inside another function (for no apparent reason: it is waiting for the DOM to be ready, but doesn't operate on the DOM) but then try to access it in the global scope (where it doesn't exist).
2. You are using `document.write` after the document has loaded. This will wipe out the existing document. Use [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML) instead.
3. You misspelt `href` as `herf`
4. You misspelt `javascript` as `javacript`, but the `type` attribute is optional (for JS) since HTML 5 and should be omitted to avoid the possibility of such typos.
5. You missed out the concatenation operator (`+`) between `dName` and  `'&#63;Subject='`
6. You are calling `$` from jQuery but have given no indication that you've loaded that library (and, as mentioned in `1` you aren't using it for anything useful anyway)

Comment: If all SO answer would be like this one it would be a wonderful world :)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're expecting the script to render some markup and place it on the page, thus replacing the script tags. Unfortunately that's now how JavaScript works. I'm guessing what you want is:

```
$(function(){
    function emailTrainer(name, userName, domain) {
        // declare your emailTrainer function as before
    };

    var $link = $(emailTrainer('Name','email','Domain');
    $('address').append($link);

});
```

Comment: you have an extra `;` after the function expression

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function emailTrainer(trainersName, userName,  domainName){
        var tName = trainersName;
        var uName = userName;
        var dName = domainName;
        var subject = 'Questions&#32;about&#32;training'

        document.write('<a herf="mailto:' + uName + '@' + dName '&#63;Subject=' + subject + '">Email ' + tName + '</a>');
    }
</script>
```

This should work.

Edited from the mobile site, so forgive the formatting

Comment: What have you changed (please let your answers be explanations and not games of spot-the-difference)? That won't work, you've left at least one error in there. (And there are errors in pieces of code you didn't quote).

Comment: The main issue he seems to obviusly facing is that hes not able to get a reference to the function and yo dont need to be genius to see that I've removed the ready function call. Also, lets not spoil him, tell him what  he's basically doing wrong, which has already been pointed out, andlethim debug and learn the language.